# Create new Dataframe from matching two dataframe index's

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking create a new dataframe from data in two separate dataframes - effectively matching the index of each cell and input into a two column dataframe. My real datasets have the exact same number of rows and columns, FWIW. Example  below:

```
 DF1:
 Col1  Col2  Col3
  1     2     3
  3     8     7

 DF2:
 Col1  Col2  Col3
  A     B     E
  R     S     W
```

Desired Dataframe:

```
 Col1  Col2
   1    A
   2    B
   3    E
   3    R
   8    S
   7    W
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: my desired dataframe does not need a col3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily like so:

```
list1 = df1.values.tolist()
list1 = [item for sublist in list1 for item in sublist]

list2 = df2.values.tolist()
list2 = [item for sublist in list2 for item in sublist]

 df = {
          'Col1': list1,
          'Col2': list2
      }

df = DataFrame(df)
print(df)
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

here is your code

```
df3 = pd.Series(df1.values.ravel('F'))
df4 = pd.Series(df2.values.ravel('F'))
df = pd.concat([df3, df4], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use, [`DataFrame.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) and [`.flatten`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Col1': df1.to_numpy().flatten(), 'Col2': df2.to_numpy().flatten()})
```

---

```
# print(df)

   Col1 Col2
0     1    A
1     2    B
2     3    E
3     3    R
4     8    S
5     7    W
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.concat(map(lambda x: x.unstack().sort_index(level=-1), (df1, df2)), axis=1).reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns=['Col1', 'Col2'].__getitem__)
```

Result:

```
   Col1 Col2
0     1    A
1     2    B
2     3    E
3     3    R
4     8    S
5     7    W
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way (alternative):

```
pd.concat((df1.stack(),df2.stack()),axis=1).add_prefix('Col').reset_index(drop=True)
```

or:

```
d = {'Col1':df1,'Col2':df2}
pd.concat((v.stack() for k,v in d.items()),axis=1,keys=d.keys()).reset_index(drop=True)
#or pd.concat((d.values()),keys=d.keys()).stack().unstack(0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
  Col1 Col2
0     1    A
1     2    B
2     3    E
3     3    R
4     8    S
5     7    W
```